Early session and cookie sign-out in ASP.NET Core
The system logs me out before 30 minutes, despite setting a 7-day expiration in Program.cs.
It must be mentioned that I checked my Chrome application section and saw the expiration file for my cookie is equal 2025.
Chrome Application Section
I changed my code several times but it doesn't work at all!
I've been thinking about my middleware, may that code is caused the problem!
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;    
}).AddCookie(option =>
{
    option.LoginPath = new PathString("/home/login");
    option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    option.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/");

    option.SlidingExpiration = false;  
    option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;  
    option.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    option.Cookie.Name = "UserAuthCookie";

}).AddGoogle("GOOGLE_LOGIN", option =>
{
    option.ClientId = "0000000000000-0000000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    option.ClientSecret = "0000000000-0000000000000";
    option.CallbackPath = "/home/GoogleLoginCallback/";
    option.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/login");
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}).AddGoogle("GOOGLE_SIGNUP", option =>
{
    option.ClientId = "00000000-000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    option.ClientSecret = "00000000000-0000000000";
    option.CallbackPath = "/home/GoogleSignupCallback/";
    option.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/signup");
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://filmnamenevisan.ir") 
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowCredentials()); // allow cookies
});
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "UserAuthCookie";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; 
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; 
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.SlidingExpiration = false; 
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy(RolesConstants.King, policy => policy.RequireRole(RolesConstants.King));
    option.AddPolicy(RolesConstants.Admin, policy => policy.RequireRole(RolesConstants.Admin));
    option.AddPolicy(RolesConstants.Expert, policy => policy.RequireRole(RolesConstants.Expert));
    option.AddPolicy(RolesConstants.User, policy => policy.RequireRole(RolesConstants.User));
});

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "UserSession";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(7); 
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;   
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; 
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");    
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.UseMiddleware<CookieMiddleware>();
UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization()

And my middleware to reissue the users' session:
public class CookieMiddleware
{
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
     private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

     public CookieMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
     {
         _next = next;
         _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
     }

     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
     {
         if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         {
             if (!context.Session.Keys.Contains("UserSession") || !context.Session.TryGetValue("UserSession:user-id", out _))
             {
                 context.Session.SetString("UserSession:user-id", ClaimUtility.GetUserId(context.User as ClaimsPrincipal).ToString());
                 context.Session.SetString("UserSession:user-nickname", ClaimUtility.GetUserFullname(context.User as ClaimsPrincipal));

                 using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                 {
                     var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserFacade>();

                     var retrieve = dbContext.GetUserUsernameHeadshotByIdService.Execute(new RequestGetUserUsernameHeadshotByIdServiceDto
                     {
                         UserId = Guid.Parse(context.Session.GetString("UserSession:user-id")),
                     });

                     if (retrieve != null)
                     {
                         if (retrieve.Username != null) context.Session.SetString("UserSession:user-username", retrieve.Username);
                         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retrieve.Headshot))
                             context.Session.SetString("UserSession:user-privateheadshot", GeneralConstants.PublicHeadshot);
                         else
                             context.Session.SetString("UserSession:user-privateheadshot", $"/UploadedStuff/user/images/user-headshot/{retrieve.Headshot}-thumb.jpg");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         context.Session.SetString("UserSession:user-privateheadshot", GeneralConstants.PublicHeadshot);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         await _next(context);
     }
 }


Try to use option.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);, instead of option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);, and let me know if it works for you.

From what I understand, ExpireTimeSpan specifies the validity period of the authentication, not the cookie. That's why we can try to use MaxAge.

@ason-pan thanks a lot! "Expire/Max-Age" is solved, but again the user throws out after 30 min. I remove all options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7); and add option.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7); instead. please check my main code and give me another advice. I will appreciate it.

Hi @Ali.M Eghbaldar, try to use option.SlidingExpiration = true;, and waiting for your reply.

Hi again dude, @ason-pan. I changed but didn't work! :(

The new thing I just discovered is that your advice worked on LOCALHOST but not worked on SERVER  @ason-pan :-o
